# Как сделать перевод строки в цикле

Tags: javascript

```
    var cell = 10;
    var row = 10;
    var clon; 
    function createDOM() {
        /* Создайте в элементе div таблицу с помощью методов DOM */
        var e = document.getElementById('d');// выбран элемент div id = "d" 
        var t = document.createElement('table');//создан <table>
        var x = e.appendChild(t); //table добавлен в div d
        var crt = document.createElement('caption');// создан caption 
        var cap = e.firstChild.appendChild(crt); //caption добавлен в table 
        var capTxt = document.createTextNode('head');// создан текстовый узел
        crt.appendChild(capTxt);// текст добавлен в caption 
        var tb = document.createElement('tbody');//создан tbody 
        var restb = t.appendChild(tb);// tbody добавлен в table
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');//создан tr
        var resTbody = tb.appendChild(tr);//tr добавлен в tbody
        var td = document.createElement('td');//создан td
        var resTd = tr.appendChild(td);//td добавлен в tr
        for(var j = 0; j < cell; j++){
            for(var i = 0; i < row; i++){
        clon = resTd.cloneNode();//клонирован td
        tr.appendChild(clon);//добавлен в tr
        clon += i;
    }
    //здесь нужен переход на новую строку
  }
}

<body>
<a href="javascript:createDOM();">Создать таблицу с помощью методов DOM</a><br>
<div id="d"></div>  
</body>
```

Comment: переход на новую строку не осуществляется

Comment: а можно пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) выложить?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vsmrxtv3/

Comment: перевод строки вставить можно так `"\n"`

Comment: @Jean `\n` - понятно. Вопрос: как его вставить в нужное место? С помощью какого метода?

Comment: зачем это вообще делать? это же динамический кусок кода и нигде его кроме файрбуга не посмотришь, а там он сам все форматирует как надо.

Comment: я учусь, а с этой целью пытаюсь разбираться и намерен разобраться во ВСЕХ мелочах. Вот для этого и надо. К сути: перевод строки нужен для того, чтобы(по моему мнению) напечатать 10 строк таблицы, а не в один ряд

Comment: к слову: `document.write("\n");` затирает данные со страницы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у таблиц нет такого понятия как *перевод строки*.

В коде в вопросе у тебя создается только одна строка - она и будет показана, как одна строка.

Если нужно получать несколько строк - то и создавать надо несколько строк.

Поэтому первый цикл должен идти по строкам, и создавать строку каждый раз, а второй по столбцам и добавлять созданные ячейки в текущую строку.

```js
var cell = 10;
var row = 10;
var clon;

function createDOM() {
  /* Создайте в элементе div таблицу с помощью методов DOM */
  var e = document.getElementById('d'); // выбран элемент div id = "d" 
  var t = document.createElement('table'); //создан <table>
  var x = e.appendChild(t); //table добавлен в div d
  var crt = document.createElement('caption'); // создан caption 

  var cap = t.appendChild(crt); //caption добавлен в table 
  var capTxt = document.createTextNode('head'); // создан текстовый узел
  crt.appendChild(capTxt); // текст добавлен в caption 
  var tb = document.createElement('tbody'); //создан tbody 
  var restb = t.appendChild(tb); // tbody добавлен в table
  for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    var tr = tb.appendChild(document.createElement('tr')); //создан tr добавлен в tbody
    for (var j = 0; j < cell; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('td'); //создан td
      td.innerHTML = `(${i}, ${j})`;
      var resTd = tr.appendChild(td); //td добавлен в tr
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:createDOM();">Создать таблицу с помощью методов DOM</a>
<div id="d"></div>
```

Comment: Как здорово иметь дело с понимающим человеком! Спасибо.

Comment: @Proshka, самое интересное, что решения у всех примерно одинаковые

Comment: я по аналогии, как в языке С, предполагал, что вывожу нужное количество элементов в строку и далее в нужный момент перехожу на новую строку и так далее. Типа, как нарисовать символами какой-нибудь рисунок

Comment: @Proshka, ну да, здесь немного по другому, потому что работа не на уровне строк идет

Comment: Еще раз - респект за понимание и помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Я правильно понимаю, вам нужно было что-то подобное?

```js
var link = document.getElementById('createDom');
link.addEventListener('click', createDOM);

var cells = 10;
var rows  = 10;

function createDOM(event) {
  if(event && event.preventDefault)
    event.preventDefault();
  
  var t = document.createElement('table');
  t.setAttribute('border', 1);
  t.setAttribute('width', '100%');
  document.getElementById('d').appendChild(t); 
  
  var caption = document.createElement('caption');
  caption.innerHTML = 'head'; 
  t.appendChild(caption);
  
  var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
  t.appendChild(tbody);
  
  var tableCells = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    tableCells += '<tr>';
  
    var cellsHtml = '';
    for (var j = 0; j < cells; j++)
      tableCells += '<td></td>';
 
    tableCells += '</tr>';
  }

  tbody.innerHTML = tableCells;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="createDom">Создать таблицу с помощью методов DOM</a>
<div id="d"></div>
```

Comment: вопрос был такой: как сделать перевод строки в цикле?

Comment: Не совсем понятно где вы ходите этот перевод строки осуществить? В html или визуально? Или после каждой таблицы должен быть отступ? Конкретику пишите

Comment: мне нужен визуальный вывод таблицы 10 строк по 10 ячеек . Перевод строки нужен после вывода в каждой строке 10 ячеек. Внутренний цикл выводит ячейки `td` - 10 штук, после этого выходим из внутреннего цикла во внешний и нужно перейти на новую строку, чтобы вывести внутренним циклом еще 10 ячеек. И так 10 рядов. Так понятно?

Comment: Ааа, так вам в конечном коде нужен перевод строки между тегами. А вы где этот конечный код смотрите? В отладчике?

Comment: конечный результат я вижу на обычной странице html, загруженной в браузере. Там должна отобразиться таблица 10 на 10

Comment: Да, сложно. Я спрошу по-другому: как вы просматриваете код, в котором не обнаруживается этот перевод строки

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49556/discussion-between-vasya-shmarovoz-and-proshka).

Answer (score 0):

Я решил свою проблему вот так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cell = 10;
    var row = 10;   
    function createDOM() {
        var div = document.getElementById('d');
        var t = document.createElement('table');
        div.appendChild(t);
        for(var i = 1; i <= cell; i++){
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            t.appendChild(tr);
            for(var j = 1; j <= row; j++){
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                var txt = document.createTextNode(i*j);
                tr.appendChild(td);
                td.appendChild(txt);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:createDOM();">Создать таблицу с помощью методов DOM</a>     <br>
<div id="d"></div>
</body>
```

Вот так я выкрутился, но, фактически, на вопрос не ответил: как сделать перевод строки в цикле?

Comment: А вы не ответили на вопрос зачем вам нужен перевод строки и где он должен быть. Если в цикле, как в пишете, ну сделайте перевод строки в цикле и всё. Если же этот перевод строки должен где-то выводиться, пишите где конкретно

Comment: в коде под вопросом КОНКРЕТНО написано, где должен быть перевод строки. Если непонятен вопрос, еще раз: как сделать переход на новую строку? В коде закомментировано конкретное место, где должен осуществляться переход на новую строку

Comment: В коде закомментировано ВНЕ функции, вам может казаться это логичным, но людям, отвечающим на ваш вопрос не совсем и не совсем понятно что значит перевод строки, это может быть тег <br>, а может быть в коде, но если в коде, то это бесполезно. Потому что DOM-методы не создают код, а создаю элементы DOM-дереве

Comment: В коде закомментировано ВНУТРИ функции, если быть немножко повнимательнее. Комментарий находится во ВНЕШНЕМ цикле.

Comment: Вижу, да, прошу прощения, табуляция ввела в заблуждение.